# Выбор IDE для создания мобильных приложений на. Java

Tags: java, ide

Я хочу скачать VS.
Чем отличается vs комьюнити 2017 от vs код.И какой вариант лучше для того чтобы писать приложения на java(с учётом добавления SQL,JS)?

Comment: Я хочу купить корову. Чем отличается корова от быка? И какой вариант лучше, чтобы производить козье молоко? (С учётом добавления сыра и клубники)?

Answer (score 3):

Для Ява есть только два приемлимых (и почти одинаковых) варианта - `Intellij IDEA` и `Android Studio`. Первая более универсальная, вторая чуть сильнее заточена под андроид. Однако платформа одна, и они практически идентичны. Другие варианты можете даже не рассматривать (`eclipse`, если вы уж совсем отчаянный, но точно не `vs`).

Comment: чем плох xamarin, например?

Comment: @Санаев а с каких пор там можно свободно на яве пилить?)

Comment: не увидел "java"